# Set video output quality for mediastore camera on all ROMs and OEM skins in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm currently using the code given below to record video from the default camera app on an android device. It works perfectly and gives me low quality video output on stock android 4.2.2. However, when i test this out on a Samsung based Touchwiz ROM the default camera app ignores the intent extra for low video quality and produces large sized videos which is not something I want. How do I make sure this intent extra works in all camera apps regardless of the android skin the device is running on?

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent,ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

PS: I do not wish to create my own camera activity as the user will lose out on a lot of other capturing options, plus, it will be tedious and time consuming.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make sure this intent extra works in all camera apps regardless of the android skin the device is running on?

You can't. You are not in control; the app that the user chooses to handle the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` request is in control. That does not have to be tied to whatever you think an "android skin" is -- the app could be a third-party app that the user has installed.

Your extras are *requests* for behavior. They are not *commands*. An app is welcome to ignore them as desired. Ideally, apps won't ignore those, but, then again, ideally, I'd have hair.

> I do not wish to create my own camera activity as the user will lose out on a lot of other capturing options, plus, it will be tedious and time consuming

Then do not complain when other apps do what those apps' authors wanted to, which may include ignoring some of the requests you made via the extras.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Also, I'm not furious or complaining, just asking for some help and suggestions. Is there any way I can specify resolution according to pixels, like 480p or 360p? That would do too.

Comment: @NewOverHere: "I'm not furious or complaining" -- and here I don't mean "complaining" as meaning that your requests are invalid, just that they are requests. "Is there any way I can specify resolution according to pixels, like 480p or 360p?" -- I don't believe that there is an `Intent` extra for that (and, once again, the app responding to the `startActivity()` call would be welcome to ignore that extra too).

Comment: this is unfortunate. i'm doing some research myself in to handling this. so @CommonsWare if you had this problem, what would you do? roll your own? i didn't realize that these parameters were simply requests until i found samsung phones not functioning as desired as mentioned above and started looking around.

Comment: @MrTristan: "if you had this problem, what would you do? roll your own?" -- since I'm writing a library for it, yes. :-) https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Comment: @CommonsWare now THAT is some good news. i really appreciate it, and applaud your work on SO. very interesting bit of business there. i must ask given your use of "writing" instead of "wrote" and the low version number; whaddya think about this being prime-time ready?

Comment: @MrTristan: "whaddya think about this being prime-time ready?" -- that depends on timing, mostly. I have only tested this on the listed devices so far, and there's gonna be plenty of quirky devices that I'm going to have to work through (see outstanding issue about Droid Incredible 2 as an example). I'm going to be working on it frequently for the forseeable future, adding features and improving compatibility. If you need to ship tomorrow, I'd be nervous. If you're looking to ship in November, and don't mind helping out with quirky results, I'd be more comfortable.

Comment: very interesting. after chatting this up with the boss it seems like i'll definitely be digging in to this in the coming week or two and would be up to submitting whatever help i'm capable of. you'll at the very least have one more beta tester on your hands :-) that's insane that you've gotta worry about developing code at the device level. fragmentation at it's finest haha.

Comment: @MrTristan: The closer you get to hardware, the more variances between devices become prominent. The camera and the sensor suite are probably the two worst culprits, in terms of what ordinary developers are likely to encounter. But it was the very problems you are seeing with relying on third-party camera apps that made me decide to take the plunge and try to write a library that's easy to use but smooths over the rough device edges. If you have questions on CWAC-Camera use, SO (tag:commonsware) is good; if you encounter bugs, file issues on the repo.